# Как поставить иконку в MenuItem C#?

Tags: c#, winforms

Вроде бы простой вопрос, только я не нашел соответствующего свойства в списке. Возможно ли это вообще? Прошу не предлагать ToolStripMenuItem.

Comment: Вот именно, нет такого свойства. Поэтому используйте Strip. Ну или рисуйте вручную в событии `DrawItem`.

Comment: Вот я и спрашиваю про DrawItem. Можете дать ссылку на реализацию?

Comment: В документации есть [пример](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.menuitem.drawitem?view=netframework-4.8#-------). Можете рисовать что угодно.

Comment: Спасибо, теперь все понятно.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov оформите ответ? вы раньше идею подсказали =)

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, можете сделать пример? Документации не хватает для реализации.

Comment: @rdorn - посмотрел я на это дело, попробовал накодить... Там проблема с определением размеров... Ну его нафик :) Сложнаааа.

Comment: А возможно поставить иконку через WinAPI?

Comment: Не задавайте вопросы в комментариях. Создайте новую тему про WinAPI. PS: вы серьёзно надеетесь получить решение для мёртвого компонента с использованием чужеродной технологии?

Comment: Дополню. Контролы WinForms - это управляемые обёртки поверх компонентов WinAPI. Поэтому да, с помощью WinAPI в теории можно добавить иконку в меню. Но делать это нужно будет так же с помощью рисования вручную. Если вы не осилили сделать это в WinForms, то с помощью инвока нативного кода это тем более сделать намного сложнее.

Comment: Недавно вышла новая версия .NET Core 3.1. В ней убрали поддержку некоторых устаревших компонентов WinForms. В частности, `MainMenu` и `MenuItem`. Если есть хоть малейший шанс, что ваш проект будет долгоживущим и будет портирован на Core - используйте Strip-компоненты.

Comment: Ну если положение безвыходное - придётся.

Answer (score 3):

После обсуждения в комментариях мой ответ такой:

Не используйте устаревшие компоненты `MainMenu` и `MenuItem`.

Возьмите более новые `MenuStrip` и `ToolStripMenuItem`. В них уже предусмотрено использование изображений.

Если кто-то хочет помучиться и реализовать код правильной отрисовки картинки на `MenuItem` с использованием события `DrawItem` - желаю удачи (и поставлю плюсик). Но считаю это мазохизмом и ненужной тратой времени.

Comment: Я же просил не ссылаться на "более новые" компоненты. Здесь даже писал модератор, что их использование нежелательно для дизайна в Win Vista и выше. Можете сбросить наработки по DrawItem?

Comment: @Antinet - Я дал свой ответ. Именно его я считаю правильным. Не согласны - не принимайте; можете поставить минус. / Ждите, пока кто-то другой даст ответ. / Для дизайна в современных ОС следует использовать современные средства. MenuStrip появился до выхода Vista. / Нет у меня наработок. Просто скопируйте код из документации и используйте `Graphics.DrawImage/Graphics.DrawIcon`.

Comment: Вряд ли кто-то еще ответ даст. Вот именно, что MenuStrip создан до Vista, он ориентирован на XP. Через WinAPI можно ставить иконки MenuItem или нет?

Comment: @Antinet - Ну так `MainMenu` создан ещё раньше, он старее и хуже по возможностям. Вы можете продолжать ждать ответа, в получении которого сами сомневаетесь. А можете просто взять другой компонент и радоваться жизни.

Answer (score 3):

Можно нарисовать, но если беретесь рисовать, то готовьтесь рисовать не только иконку, но и все эффекты, вроде нажато/не нажато, активно/не активно и т.д. и т.п. для всех интересующих вас статусов.

В примере я не буду приводить все возможные варианты, только необходимый минимум.

```
//включаем пользовательскую отрисовку
mi.OwnerDraw = true;
//событие, которое срабатывает перед отрисовкой элемента меню для определения его размера
mi.MeasureItem += Mi_MeasureItem;
//событие рисования элемента
mi.DrawItem += Mi_DrawItem;

private void Mi_MeasureItem(object sender, MeasureItemEventArgs e)
{
    //вычисляем размер кнопки меню и фиксируем
    e.ItemWidth = GetContentWidth();
    e.ItemHeight = GetContentHeight();
    //методы вычисления размера контента придется писать самостоятельно

    //Если контент содержит только текст, можно использовать e.Graphics.MeasureString(...)
}


//ну и наконец рисуем контент
private void Mi_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(Properties.Resources.MyButtonImage, e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y, e.Bounds.Height, e.Bounds.Height);
    e.Graphics.DrawString((sender as MenuItem).Text, DefaultFont, Brushes.Red, e.Bounds.X + e.Bounds.Height, e.Bounds.Y);
}
```

С одной стороны - можно делать что хочешь, с другой - а оно вам надо все-все-все прописывать своими руками. Вас предупреждали. В целом я тоже считаю, что не стоит использовать компоненты, которые даже сами MS уже не рекомендуют использовать, если только в этом нет острой необходимости для какой-либо специфичной обратной совместимости.

---

Отдельно хочу заметить, что данный способ кастомной отрисовки контента в формах применяется не только в устаревших MenuItem, для которых предоставлена более функциональная замена, но также для кастомизации элементов ListBox, его производных и еще некоторых контролов, которые довольно активно используются в различных приложениях.

Правда вот необходимость такой кастомизации для меня остается под большим вопросом, т.к. для создания модных интерфейсов с рюшечками в каждом пикселе по желанию заказчика, проще (спорно) и быстрее (однозначно) использовать WPF, UWP или их кросс-платформенные аналоги, вроде AvaloniaUI. Я не отдаю предпочтения какому-то конкретному UI-фреймворку, просто у каждого инструмента есть своя область применения, а действительно красивые и настраиваемые интерфейсы на любой вкус - это не про WinForms. Нет, разумеется все возможно, вопрос сколько понадобится времени для качественной реализации необходимых визуальных эффектов.